# When we move subviews from one view to the other what will happen to the subviews' frame?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

I notice 2 different things.

When I do this via program the subviews' frame does not change.

When i do this in interface builder, the subviews' frame is all in the middle.

This is for iOS. I am not sure about MaCos.

I am not sure where do all this is documented. And how does autoresize mask affect this.

Answer (score 0):

I think when we move subviews from one view to the other through code then the frame of the subview remains at the same coordinates as it was aligned with the previous parent view, means if subview's x coordinate was at a distance of 10 pixels from parent's x coordinate then this subview will be at 10 pixels from the new parent view and same will happen for y coordinate  but in case of interface builder the subviews aligns its center to the s=center of the parent view.

Comment: Does autoresize mask affect this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your view as it appears on Simulator screen. What I mean by this is for example if your application launches with Status bar, before adding your subviews it is prefered to put statusbar into root view. In addition to this, Your view's 'Clip Bounds' and Auto Resize SubViews properties are playing significant role. These properties might encounter the problems you have faced.